# binding json array response to row of list in listview in xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin

I am binding json data from a response to a list.

**Response**

```
[{
    "DDLValue":"home",
    "ID":2,
    "Msg":"Enough",
    "Status":2
}
  {
    "DDLValue":"palace",
    "ID":1,
    "Msg":"good",
    "Status":2
}]
```

I'm able to bind the above json response to a `ListView`, but I want a first row that contains the word "select" and all following rows the response.

**Mainactivity.cs**

```
tableItems = new List<TableItem>();
var client = new RestClient("http://websites.net/");
var request = new RestRequest("Service/GetRegions", Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
tableItems = client.Execute<List<TableItem>>(request).Data;

listView.Adapter = new HomeScreenAdapter(this, tableItems);
    protected void OnListItemClick(object sender, Android.Widget.AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
                   string val;
        if (e.Position==0)
        { 
            region.Text = -select-;
        }
        else {


       var  t1 = tableItems[e.Position-1];
            val = t1.DDLValue;
            region.Text = val;
        }}
```

**HomeScreenAdapter.cs**

```
public class HomeScreenAdapter : BaseAdapter<TableItem> {
    List<TableItem> items;
    Activity context;
    public HomeScreenAdapter(Activity context, List<TableItem> items)
        : base()
    {

        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override TableItem this[int position]
    {
        get { return items[position]; }
    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get { return items.Count+1; }
    }
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = items[position];

        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomView, null);
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text1).Text = item.DDLValue;

        return view;
    }
}
```

How can I add an extra first row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        TableItem item;

        if (position == 0 {
          item = new TableItem { DDLValue = "Select" };
        } else {
          item = items[position - 1];
        }

        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomView, null);
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text1).Text = item.DDLValue;

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: In listview first row appears to be select option,but when i click on particular listrow ,it gives TableItem object of next row(i mean details of next row)and when clicked on select row it gives arrayout of bond exception.

Comment: In your list click event handler, you will need to modify the index to account for the "empty" item at the start of the list.

Comment: Thanks Jason.I did using if else condition and checking for position zero.see my updated answer.and Please correct me if it is not right way of checking.

Comment: in you if case, do NOT modify the TableItems array.  Instead just set the value region.Text = "-Select";  Your else case appears correct.

Comment: one more error, TableItems array is 6,if i add select in first row of listview ,last object of tableitem array response  is not getting binded to listview.

Comment: you need to change your Count property to reflect the "select" row you have at the beginning.

Comment: once again thankyou for guiding me,by changing count to count+1 it worked.