# how to retrieve object on click of particular row in tableLayout in xamarin C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

i am trying to create a tablelayout,where data from service get binded to rows of table.Here i want these things to happen

1.)First row of tablelayout should be Default given(that is "Select item" in my case).

2.)Onclick of any particular row i should be able to retrieve that particular object value.

3.)to put red color divider between rows

below is my code used

```
 TableLayout tl = FindViewById<TableLayout>(Resource.Id.maintable);

            var client = new RestClient("http://sitemakong.net/");
            var request = new RestRequest("Service/HeadingSearch", Method.POST);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            List<TableHeading> tableItems = client.Execute<List<TableHeading>>(request).Data;
           int countValue = tableItems.Count;
            TableHeading Tablevalues = new TableHeading();

            for (int i = 0; i < countValue; i++)
            {
                tableItems[0] = new TableHeading { HeadingID = 1, Heading = "_select_", SubHeading = "Hi"};

                Tablevalues = tableItems[i];
                var Heading = Tablevalues.Heading;
                id = Heading;

                //Create a new row to be added.
                tr = new TableRow(this);

                tr.Id = i;
                int rowId = tr.Id;
                tr.SetTag(Resource.Id.rowId, tr);
                tv = new TextView(this);
                createView(tr, tv, id.ToString());
                tl.AddView(tr);
            }
        }

        //Method

        private void createView(TableRow tr, TextView t, String viewdata)
        {

            t.SetText(viewdata, TextView.BufferType.Editable);

            //You have to use Android.Graphics.Color not System.ConsoleColor;
            t.SetTextColor(Color.Blue);
            t.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Cyan);
            t.SetPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);

            tr.SetPadding(0, 1, 0, 1);
            tr.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Black);
                      tr.Clickable = true;
                  tr.AddView(t); // add TextView to row.


        }

        public void HandleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var clickedTableRow = sender as TableRow;
      //      string strval = clickedTableRow.gett;
            int s = clickedTableRow.Id;

            var tag = clickedTableRow.GetTag(s);


            //GET TEXT HERE
          //  Toast.MakeText(this, tag + " hi  string " + strval, ToastLength.Long).Show();

            Toast.MakeText(this, tag + " hi " + s, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
```

I am new to xamarin and c#.Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   public void HandleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var clickedTableRow = sender as TableRow;
        int s = clickedTableRow.Id;

        // s is the index of the row, so just retrieve the matching object
        // from the data source
        var selected = tableItems[s];

    }
```

to create the "special" row at the start of your table, you could just create a dummy element at the start of your datasource

```
List<TableHeading> tableItems = client.Execute<List<TableHeading>>(request).Data;

// create a dummy TableHeading, insert it at the start of the list
tableItems.Insert(0, new TableHeading { .. set the appropriate properties here .. });

int countValue = tableItems.Count;
```

then let your for loop execute and build the table - you will need to remove the line `tableItems[0] = ...`

Comment: how could i set default object value in the first row and repeat view for bottom border.

Comment: you can either add placeholder value in your datasource, or add a special condition in your view (and click handler) to treat the 1st row differently than the others.

Comment: i am using this condition  "  tableItems[0] = new TableHeading { HeadingID = 1, Heading = "_select_", SubHeading = "Hi"};
 "   inside for loop for default object.This will appear but overlap with first json json object.

Comment: didn't we address that problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36224037/binding-json-array-response-to-row-of-list-in-listview-in-xamarin-android

Comment: here for tablerow there is no position for eventclick. I am not getting could u show me some code for this.Please

Comment: in **your** code you are setting the ID of the TableRow to be the index value of your loop.  So in your click handler you can grab the ID and use that as the index.

Comment: here default row ("which includes select text ")it is overlaping with first json response object.first i need all rows with default object and json objects to show.then only i can  get id to handle clickevent.

Comment: thanks jason i learned new insert method and its use from your answer.It was really helpful for me

Comment: @    strange thing is happening now,this works in debug mode with no crash.but in release mode app crashes from this line tableItems.Insert(0, new TableItem {  HeadingID = 1, Heading = "_select_", SubHeading = "Hi" });
could you tell me what is happening here.there is no wrong in logic.Anyways no code related to api level then what is wrong here?.

Comment: You need to check the stacktrace to see which exception is causing the crash.